# how to add two dropdowns parallel to each other

Tags: civimail, civievent, civicontribute, civimember, contacts

[image]how to add two dropdowns parallel to each other, e.g. one drop down with name of the item and the second dropdown with the quantity of the item. I have tried to add two dropdowns but they appeared one below thee other. Basically what are I'm trying to do is to have an "Item" correspond to the "Quantity" to how many were sold. Please check the image below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write JavaScript in order to view the drop drown parallel.

If you are trying this in summary screen just use tab.extra.tpl else please let me know the screen so I will help you.